# Move canvas to touch event in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to move a canvas, I've searched but nothing solved this problem. I've tried different ways but my canvas seems to move almost randomly, I can see that sometimes it goes near where I clicked.

```
public void update() {
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
}

public void dash(double x, double y) {
    dashY = y;
    dashX = x;
    dx = (int) dashX - this.x;
    dy = (int) dashY - this.y;
    distance = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy));
    vy = speed*dy/distance;
    vx = speed*dx/distance;
}
```

I call dash with event.getX() and event.getY() from a onTouchEvent.
I want it to go through where I clicked, using the shortest path (distance).
The variable speed is a constant.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is this a custom view? If that's the case, you can't really **move** the `canvas` that's supplied in `onDraw(canvas)`.

Comment: @Henry yes it's a custom view, then what can I do to move the canvas?

Comment: In the custom view, whatever you see is the canvas. So you can't move it? You can move your drawings inside the canvas, but not the canvas. What is your actual requirement?

Comment: My bad, I'm not trying to move the canvas, I'm trying to move the drawing, my bad, sorry.